# can't access property of object inside directive

Tags: angularjs

When a user clicks a button in my application, I try to compile a directive like this and send the document (a complex json object) that was clicked on to the directive

```
$scope.displayBlah = function(event, document){

  $scope.doc = document; 
  $(event.currentTarget.parentElement).prepend($compile('<show-blah mydata={{doc}}/>')($scope));

}
```

Inside the directive code, I want to access individual properties on that object but am only able to display the whole object, without being able to use dot notation to get at the properties. For example, this shows the whole complex object

```
{{mydata}}
```

but I can't get at any indiviual property like this

```
{{mydata.property}}
```

This is what I do

```
myApp.directive('showBlah', function(){
return {
            restrict: 'AE', 
            scope: {
                mydata: '@'
                 }
            replace: true, 
            template: <div class='root'>{{mydata}} {{mydata.property}}</div>,
            link: ///code ommitted
```

Question: Is it possible to access a property inside an object in a directive like this?

```
 {{mydata.property}}
```

Comment: Are you really writing `mydata{{doc}}`? Because that won't be valid HTML.

Comment: @Thomas no that was a typo. I'll fix the OP. thank you

Comment: By the way, this sort of DOM modification is rarely necessary in Angular. Why not stick `<show-blah ng-if="doc" mydata="{{doc}}"/>` into the template instead?

Comment: this is my first angular project so I appreciate the tip but I actually don't think that would work in my case. The doc already exists in the template, so the `ng-if` would always be true. The reasons I'm doing this is that there are cases dependent on user interaction where I have to display a second instance of the same `doc` with stylistic modifcations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `@` here turns the incoming value into a string:

```
        scope: {
            mydata: '@'
             }
```

That explains why `{{mydata}}` works (just shows a string), but `{{mydata.property}}` doesn't (strings don't have that `property`).

Use `=` instead (and leave out the `{{ }}` in the directive invocation).

Comment: so leaving out the {{ }} in the directive invocation means doing this? `mydata=doc` ?  as in `$(event.currentTarget.parentElement).prepend($compile('<show-blah mydata=doc/>')($scope));` ?

Comment: Yes. When you use `=` or `&` for binding, Angular expects an Angular expression, not an interpolated string. On the other hand, with `@`, it expects a string which might contain interpolated parts (using `{{ }}`).